# SSO for Tomcat users with SPNEGO fails

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, spnego

I have an app running on tomcat server. This app authenticates with Active directory using `SPNEGO` module.

Steps we take make this setup work are:

1. Add `Tomcat APP` to the `AD` domain
2. Make a `REST API` login call to the APP. This `REST API` call will perform authentication/authorization to AD using `SPNEGO`.

As a part of the brand new APP initialization, we start the app for the first time and add this app-host to AD domain. Then make the API call which performs AD authorization fails with following error.

Type Exception report:

```
message GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:238)
root cause

GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:234)
root cause

KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC
    sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:234)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.
```

This indicates that SPNEGO is not able to find the key to decrypt the communication with AD.

The problem goes away as I restart the tomcat. After this restart if Tomcat, user can SUCCESSFULLY perform SSO based authorization.

I checked keytab file and everything looks ok. We are using RC4-HMAC encryption for this purpose. Also login.conf and krb5.conf are configured correctly on the host. ( As after the restart everything works fine )

I ran strace on tomcat pid to see if SPNEGO reads the keytab file. It appears that Tomcat/SPNEGO is calling stat on the file, but never opening it. Tomcat/SPNEGO thinks that whatever it's cached is still correct.

Here's the lines for that call:

```
7832  1431560872.430550 stat("/var/pgsql/sync-dir/samba/tomcat-user.keytab",  <unfinished ...>
7832  1431560872.443416 <... stat resumed> {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=894, ...}) = 0
```

I never see it *read* it though.

Please let me know if anyone has seen this issue of `SPNEGO` caching information and the problem goes away as we restart Tomcat